# Pagination in CodeIgniter doesn't work with passing parameters

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

Creating pagination in CodeIgniter doesn't seem to work for me when using URL parameters, when I navigate to page 2 it tells me "page not found"

In the controller

```
// pagination settings
$config["total_rows"] = $this->product_model->hitungdata($itemid);
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'pagination/'.$itemid.'?offset='.$offset;
$config['uri_segment'] = '3';
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['per_page'] = 25;

// integrate bootstrap pagination
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = false;
$config['last_link'] = false;
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '«';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '»';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$data['product'] = $this->product_model->tarikdata($config["per_page"], $offset, $itemid);
$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

In the model

```
function tarikdata($limit, $offset, $itemid)
{
    $sql = "select * from allproduct where itemid = '$itemid' LIMIT $offset, $limit";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}

function hitungdata($itemid)
{
    $sql = "select * from allproduct where itemid = '$itemid'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

Comment: $config['enable_query_strings'] = true;

Comment: when i click on next page the url become like this : http://192.168.1.18/alpha/pagination/1?offset=0/2